# How to transform test data in Functional Principal Component Analysis in R

Tags: r, pca, functional-data-analysis

I am doing a functional principal component analysis on time series data, and when I finished the FPCA on train data and extracted the PCs. Next, I need to project the test data onto the PCs, here I am frustrated how to carry out this process in R.

Here are my steps to deal with the time series data with fda package in R:

1. Construct the basis functions. `create.bspline.basis`
2. Smooth basis by `smooth.basis`
3. FPCA by `pca.fd` on train dataset

Till the step 3, I gained the score and varprop, but I have no idea how to tranform the test dataset onto the same PCs as in train data.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @PeterFlom: This question has clear statistical context. Many users produce PCA results and do not know how to translate them new data. In addition to that we never had a question asking this on the context of Functional Data Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Projecting new functional data using an existing FPCA analysis is very similar to what we would do with standard PCA (for multivariate data). The main difference is that due to stochastic nature of our sampling procedure we are unable to use standard numerical integration as we would in the case of PCA to get the corresponding score but rather a probabilistic approximation of it (PACE - see reference below).

For rest of the post I will refer to $\phi$ as the functional PCs, $\xi$ as the associated FPC scores, $\lambda$ as their associated eigenvalues, $\mu$ as the sample mean and $C$ as the sample covariance. I also assume we are dealing with irregularly spaced data across a continuum $s$ and I refer to the test data at hand as $y_{test}$. 
In short, the prediction for the trajectory $y_i(s)$ using the first $K$ eigenfunctions is: $\hat{y}_i^K(s) = \hat{\mu}(s) + \sum_{k=1}^{K} \hat{\xi}_{i,k}\hat{\phi}_k(s)$.

In order to project new test data on the results of an existing FPCA we would require the following steps:

1. Ensure that $\mu$, $C$ and $\phi$ are evaluated at the same points of $s$ we have $y_{test}$ readings. If necessary, we estimate these values through interpolation techniques.
2. Centre the data to have $E\{\mu(s)\}=0$ according the $\hat\mu(s)$ we calculated during the original FPCA.
3. Predict the $\xi$ for the test data, using the fact that we expect the error of the prediction to be asymptotically Gaussian, through: $\hat{\xi}_{ik} = \hat{\lambda}_k \hat{\phi}_{ik}^T\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}_{y_i}(y_i^{obs} - \hat{\mu}_i)$. Notice that all estimates (aside $\hat{\lambda}_k$) are evaluated at the points we have observations from the $i$-th curve, i.e. they might even be just scalar in the odd case a particular sample has a single measurement. This whole procedure is what in the FDA literature is referred as the "PACE step/procedure" (PACE: Principal components Analysis through Conditional Expectation); the canonical reference on the matter is: Yao, et al. (2005) *[Functional Data Analysis for Sparse Longitudinal Data](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5449/de2bfe47a53f667b2060a91c01287a1ddfdf.pdf)* (Sect. 2.3 to be exact).

The package [`fdapace`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fdapace/index.html) implements this methodology through the function `predict.FPCA`. The package [`fda`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fda/) (most probably) implements this methodology in the function `project.basis` but I have not used it.

Comment: I was wondering after you project the PCs to test data, will the fraction of variation explained by the first K FPC scores predicted in test data differ from those in training data? In FPCA, we calculated the fraction using $\lambda$ (e.g. $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)/\sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k$), when I used variance of say first 2 FPC scores, it differed from using the first 2 eigenvalues ($\lambda$).

Comment: Asymptomatically it should reflect that, yes.